# Does every positive semidefinite hankel matrix obeys one Vandermonde decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, hankel-matrices

I'm reading [the paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8715594)(I can't find one arXiv version of this paper...) and suspect the correctness of one theorem inside. A [hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) $H$ is a square matrix in which each ascending skew-diagonal from left to right is constant. Vandemonde decomposition is to decompose $H$ as $H=V^TDV$ with $D$ diagonal matrix and $V$ the [Vandemonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Theorem I.1 of the paper states that

> Theorem I.1. For any positive semidefinite Hankel matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with rank $r, 1 \leq r<n$, there exists a Vandermonde matrix $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ and a diagonal matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ with positive diagonal entries such that $H=$ $V^T D V$.

My question is, is this statement really true? For example, if we set $n=3,r=1$ and choose $H=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  0\\
 0&  0&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right) $. Then $H$ is hankel and does not have a Vandemonde decomposition if we require elements of $D$ to be positive.